# Find directory and get its absolute path

Tags: java, file

I have a directory name "/my-directory" and I want to find it and get its absolute path. All I have is the name of the directory so I tried the following :

```
File file = new File("/my-directory");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and this returns :

> "C:\my-directory"

but my directory isn't under "C:\", so it's not doing what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `/` in front.

Comment: `file.exists()` probably returns false too...

Comment: If you have no idea where the directory is located, how could you find the right file by just creating one File object? If the problem is really to find a directory, anywhere on the file system, that is named "my-directory", then you need to traverse the whole file system until you find the directory.